After Upgrade Form Not Submitting In Safari
I recently updated the site from Magento 2.4.3 to 2.4.6. Since then a custom form (that works in other browsers, e.g. Chrome and Firefox) is redirecting to the homepage upon Submit in Safari.
In the Javascript console the only errors shown are CSP errors.
In the Magento logs there are no errors being thrown.
I have tried:

Ensuring the form key is on the page.  From inspecting the page it looks to me like the form key is being set properly
Per this question, I have tried changing the cookie settings
I have set a breakpoint in the PHP side of the form which doesn't seem to be hitting, so I believe the form is never actually being submitted but instead something on the front end is causing issues.
I have set a breakpoint in client.js's _save function. When I have a breakpoint there the form submits correctly!  Obviously this doesn't fix the issue though so I need to figure out why this is the case.

Code is below:
RecurringService/view/frontend/templates/pageactions.phtml
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

use RecurringService\ViewModel\FormKey;

/** @var FormKey $viewModel */
$viewModel = $block->getViewModel();
?>

<?php if ($block->getChildHtml()) : ?>
    <script>
        var FORM_KEY = '<?= /* @noEscape */ $viewModel->getFormKey() ?>';
    </script>
    <div>
        <?= $block->getChildHtml() ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>

RecurringService/view/frontend/layout/recurring_schedule_index.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
            <action method="setPageTitle">
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">My Service Schedule</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="service_schedule_description">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">service-schedule-description</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <uiComponent name="service_schedule_form"/>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"
                   cacheable="false"
                   name="page.actions.toolbar" template="RecurringService::pageactions.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="view_model" xsi:type="object">RecurringService\ViewModel\FormKey</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>

RecurringService/view/frontend/ui_component/service_schedule_form.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">service_schedule_form.service_schedule_form_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <buttons>
            <button name="save" class="RecurringService\Block\ServiceSchedule\Form\SaveButton"/>
        </buttons>
        <namespace>service_schedule_form</namespace>
        <dataScope>data</dataScope>
        <deps>
            <dep>service_schedule_form.service_schedule_form_data_source</dep>
        </deps>
    </settings>
    <dataSource name="service_schedule_form_data_source">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <submitUrl path="recurring/schedule/save"/>
        </settings>
        <dataProvider class="RecurringService\Model\RecurringProfile\DataProvider"
                      name="service_schedule_form_data_source">
            <settings>
                <requestFieldName>profile_id</requestFieldName>
                <primaryFieldName>entity_id</primaryFieldName>
            </settings>
        </dataProvider>
    </dataSource>
    <fieldset name="service_schedule" class="RecurringService\Ui\Component\Form\ServiceSchedule">
        <settings>
            <label translate="true">Service Schedule</label>
        </settings>
    </fieldset>
</form>

RecurringService/Block/ServiceSchedule/Form/SaveButton.php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace RecurringService\Block\ServiceSchedule\Form;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Control\ButtonProviderInterface;

/**
 * Class SaveButton
 */
class SaveButton implements ButtonProviderInterface
{
    /**
     * Gets button data
     *
     * @return mixed[]
     */
    public function getButtonData()
    {
        return [
            'label'          => __('Update Service Schedule'),
            'class'          => 'save primary',
            'data_attribute' => [
                'mage-init' => [
                    'buttonAdapter' => [
                        'actions' => [
                            [
                                'targetName' => 'service_schedule_form.service_schedule_form',
                                'actionName' => 'save'
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ];
    }
}

UPDATE:
I have confirmed that the issue is not related to CSP nor the form key.
I have a new clue.  I was able to put a breakpoint in Safari in Magento's generated client.js in the _save function.  When I add this breakpoint the form submits correctly and doesn't redirect to the homepage.  I believe the issue is some type of asynchronous issue or race condition but do not know how to track it down further.

Check Safari's console for the exact CSP errors -  what's the message in there - exactly?

@FlorinelChis
I've added them above.  I may be mistaken.  Most of them are related to various libraries and being in Report Only Mode, so I don't think they are related? But I'm not sure

You can try the below debugging steps to check exactly what the issue is for Safari.
Update your csp_whitelist.xml to allow the necessary scripts or resources:
<policies xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/csp_whitelist.xsd">
    <policy id="script-src">
        <value id="self" type="host" />
        <value id="example.com" type="host" />
    </policy>
</policies>

Form Validation or Token Issues
Magento forms often include CSRF tokens. If the token validation fails, the form might redirect incorrectly.
Debugging:
Verify the CSRF token in your form (form_key hidden input field) is being included in the POST request.
Check Magento's var/log/debug.log or exception.log for token-related errors.
Fix:
Ensure the form_key is being generated and included in the form.
In your form template, include:
<input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?= $block->getFormKey(); ?>" />

Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) or SameSite Cookie Policies
Safari has stricter handling of cookies and cross-origin requests. If your form relies on cookies (e.g., session cookies for CSRF validation), they may not be sent or recognized due to SameSite attribute enforcement.
Debugging:
Open Safari’s developer tools and check the Network tab to inspect the form submission request.
Look at the request headers and ensure cookies are being sent correctly.
Fix:
Ensure cookies have a SameSite=None and Secure attribute set if they are used in cross-origin requests.
Check Magento's session.cookie_samesite configuration:
bin/magento config:set web/cookie/cookie_samesite None
bin/magento cache:flush


Please see my edits.  I have confirmed it is not a CSP nor a form key issue. I have set a breakpoint in client.js's _save function. When I have a breakpoint there the form submits correctly, so it must be some kind of asynchronous issue but idk why or how to fix it.
